# (Eclipse) Dynamic Web Project runs correctly on J2EE preview server but not on Tomcat server

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, tomcat, server

I have a dynamic web project (along with a JAR "java standalone project"). within Eclipse, when I run the project on J2EE preview server and test one of the functionality of my project, everything works fine, but when I run it using Tomcat server and test the same functionality, an exception is caught:

**Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/TimeoutException**

it's pointing somewhere in the JAR project (the one that is set in Deployment Assembly section to be taken along with Dynamic web project).
[image]

I searched on the internet and tried different suggestions but got no result till now. How is this possible? I mean the same Project runs smoothly on one server and fails on another one considering that it's being deployed with no error on both servers?

Appreciate your time in advance and let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: You have to deploy a war to tomcat so all the dependencies are included.

Comment: Which of this jars has `org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException` in it? This exception means you compiled with it but it's simply not present at runtime on the server.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz It's not absolutely true. The project behaves in the same way either deploying war file to tomcat or run it on a tomcat server within eclipse. I've already tried it and the exception is the same.

Comment: @nitind The selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar has org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException and the project works smoothly when I depoly it on J2EE preview server within eclipse but not on Tomcat.

Comment: Is that jar being deployed to the server?

Comment: Thank you @nitind for your time. I think yes. It's inside Web App Libraries. How can I verify it? Should I check the eclipse workspace folder?

Comment: @nitind Is there any way to force Tomcat deploying a library?

Comment: I would have thought the Deployment Assembly property page was where you did that.